# Pandas sum over partition by rows following SQL equivalent

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking a way to aggregate (in pandas) a subset of values based on a particular partition, an equivalent of

```
select table.*,
       sum(income) over (order by id, num_yyyymm rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_income_3,
       sum(income) over (order by id, num_yyyymm rows between 1 following and 3 following) as next_income_3
from table order by a.id_customer, num_yyyymm;
```

I tried with the following solution but it has some problems:
1) Takes ages to complete
2) I have to merge all the results at the end of

```
for x, y in df.groupby(['id_customer']):
    print(y[['num_yyyymm', 'income']])
    y['next3'] = y['income'].iloc[::-1].rolling(3).sum()
    print(y[['num_yyyymm', 'income', 'next3']])
    break
```

Results:

```
        num_yyyymm       income     next3
0       201501         0.00     0.00
1       201502         0.00     0.00
2       201503         0.00     0.00
3       201504         0.00     0.00
4       201505         0.00     0.00
5       201506         0.00     0.00
6       201507         0.00     0.00
7       201508         0.00     0.00
8       201509         0.00     0.00
9       201510         0.00     0.00
10      201511         0.00     0.00
11      201512         0.00     0.00
12      201601         0.00     0.00
13      201602         0.00     0.00
14      201603         0.00     0.00
15      201604         0.00     0.00
16      201605         0.00     0.00
17      201606         0.00     0.00
18      201607         0.00     0.00
19      201608         0.00     0.00
20      201609         0.00  1522.07
21      201610         0.00  1522.07
22      201611         0.00  1522.07
23      201612      1522.07     0.00
24      201701         0.00    -0.00
25      201702         0.00     1.52
26      201703         0.00  1522.07
27      201704         0.00  1522.07
28      201705         1.52  1520.55
29      201706      1520.55     0.00
30      201707         0.00      NaN
31      201708         0.00      NaN
32      201709         0.00      NaN
```

Does anybody have an alternative solution?

Comment: Show execution plan of that query feels like there are missing indexes on the table..

Comment: "Does anybody have an alternative solution" is applicable only when you post an input dataframe. ow would one know what is the output based on if you don't  know the input